# POST request from Postman to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, post, controller, postman

I am trying to send a post request to a Laravel project using Postman, but I get a "419 unknown status" response

routes\web.php:

```
Route::post('/myaction', 'MymodelController@myaction');
```

app\Http\Controllers\MymodelController.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Mymodel;

class MymodelController extends Controller
{
    function myaction()
    {
        return redirect('/');
   }
}
```

Why does this happen?

The same error appears independently of the content of `myaction()`

Comment: The `csrf`? No, how can I send it through Postman?

Comment: Thank you! The solution was to use api.php instead of web.php. (Please write it as a reply, for further help to other viewers)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you are requesting api you should write your route in `api.php` instead `web.php`

`web.php` require `_token` the csrf field

Answer (score 2):

By default, Laravel use the middleware `VerifyCsrfToken`.
See [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-introduction)
for more details.

You need to add your URL to the `$excludes` field inside `VerifyCsrfToken` class.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have defined route for redirect('/'); in web.php ?

Comment: Yes `Route::get('/', function () {
     return view('welcome');
 });`
and GET request in / works properly. If I try to create a `Route::post('/'` the same 419 issue appears

Comment: in your form you must also send csrf token
{{ csrf_field() }}